Azure Portal - How to setup a Client ID and Client Secret
I want to programmatically start and stop a VM instance, if possible can someone give me the step-by-step guide to how to obtain these two values:
AZURE_CLIENT_ID
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET

Either creation via the azure cli or Azure dev ops portal is fine, I just can not understand why this process is not documented or somewhat intuitive.
I can not reference the process to do this anywhere.
I have seen this:
Attempted credentials:
        EnvironmentCredential: invalid tenantID. You can locate your tenantID by following the instructions listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/partner-center/find-ids-and-domain-names
        WorkloadIdentityCredential: no token file specified. Check pod configuration or set TokenFilePath in the options
        ManagedIdentityCredential: managed identity timed out. See https://aka.ms/azsdk/go/identity/troubleshoot#dac for more information
        AzureCLICredential: Azure CLI not found on path
        AzureDeveloperCLICredential: Azure Developer CLI not found on path
exit status 1

Yet as far as I can reference, I have supplied the correct TenantId from my Azure portal subscription?
The best I can get to is this:
RESPONSE 403: 403 Forbidden
ERROR CODE: AuthorizationFailed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
  "error": {
    "code": "AuthorizationFailed",
    "message": "The client '...' with object id '...' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action' over scope '/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/.../providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines...' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
  }
}



The code for reproduction is here:
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/azcore"
    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/azidentity"
    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/resourcemanager/compute/armcompute/v5"
)

func connectionAzure() (azcore.TokenCredential, error) {
    cred, err := azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(nil)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return cred, nil
}

func main() {
    subscriptionId := os.Getenv("AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID")

    if len(subscriptionId) == 0 {
        log.Fatal("AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID is not set.")
    }

    // Set your Azure resource group name and VM name
    resourceGroupName := "<RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>"
    virtualMachineName := "<VIRTUAL_MACHINE_NAME>"

    cred, err := connectionAzure()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cannot connect to Azure:%+v", err)
    }

    ctx := context.Background()

    client, err := armcompute.NewVirtualMachinesClient(subscriptionId, cred, nil)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cannot create Azure Virtual Machines client:%+v", err)
    }

    poller, err := client.BeginStart(ctx, resourceGroupName, virtualMachineName, &armcompute.VirtualMachinesClientBeginStartOptions{})

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cannot start Azure Virtual Machine:%+v", err)
    }

    // Call the poller object's PollUntilDone function that will block until the poller object
    // has been updated to indicate the task has completed.
    res, err := poller.PollUntilDone(ctx, nil)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cannot poll Azure Virtual Machine:%+v", err)
    }

    // Print the fact that the LRO completed.
    fmt.Printf("LRO done")

    // Print the response
    fmt.Printf("Response: %v\n", res)
}


Client IDs and Client Secrets are fundamentally different than your Tenant ID. Can you link the source which is asking for these variables? It's likely you need to set up an App Registration, which would automatically generate a Client ID and enable you to then generate an associated Client Secret. You'd then add the permission scopes you need to the associated managed identity to carry out the tasks you need it to.

@esqew So I have successfully setup a new app via the App Registration section, and a Client Secret. I have referenced these both in my environment as AZURE_CLIENT_ID and AZURE_CLIENT_SCERET, I have also supplied AZURE_TENANT_ID and AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID and I am seeing the referenced error in my question, i.e., "EnvironmentCredential: invalid tenantID. You can locate your tenantID by following the instructions listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/partner-center/find-ids-and-domain-names"

@MichealJ.Roberts You need to assign the Contributor role or a custom role (RBAC) to the App Registration to allow it to start/stop the VM.

@AJ31 Ok cool. How do I do that?

Navigate to the Virtual Machines section under the appropriate resource group where your VMs are located then select the specific virtual machine you want the App Registration to have access to and click on the "Access control (IAM)" then add Role Assignment

Follow the steps in this article link text

It's pretty difficult to say why this is erroring out this way without seeing a [mre] of the code that uses these variables. As a wild guess, there may be something amiss about the way you've fundamentally configured these for use in your code (i.e., your code isn't reading your .env file or other environment variables correctly).

@AJ31 @komluk So I have added the "Virtual Machine Contributor" role to the desired resource, and yet I still see the following error: EnvironmentCredential: invalid tenantID. Yet I have cross referenced this SEVERAL times between the portal and what I have in my environment, and it is 100% correct. I am tearing my hair out.

@esqew I have added proof that my environment credentials are setup correctly to my question, I have cross checked and verified them with my Azure portal as well. I have also added a minimal code snippet for your review in my question ... something is definitely not tallying up here, I have never struggled more with anything in my life ...

Now having seen the environment variable configuration itself, your environment variable values have quotation marks in them; I'm not familiar with a valid Tenant ID that would contain them. Seems like a typo to me.

Ok, with the environment variable change (dropping the quotes), I am back to the does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action' over scope even though I have added the role Virtual Machines Contributor to that resource ...

Try adding the Contributor role

I have added the Virtual Machines Contributor role ... please let me know how I add the Contributor role ... I can not reference that role. Please be as verbose as possible.

Go to VM -> Access Control -> Add -> Add Role Assignment -> Priveleged Administrator roles -> Contributor and then add your user.

As a point of clarity to @AJ31's comment, add the identity of the App Registration for which you possess the Client ID and Client Secret values.

@AJ31 I have followed those steps and I still get the same error.

@esqew Please be as verbose as you can, I can not find where to add the identity of the App Registration ... what are the steps? (P.S. God this is F*****G overly complicated!). Quicker just to press the damn "Start" button.

@MichealJ.Roberts Can you please update the code with the the environment setting update? options := azidentity.DefaultAzureCredentialOptions{}     options.IncludeEnvironmentCredential = true     cred, err := azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(&options)

Jesus Halalulah I have managed to start a VM programatically, the App Registration is obfuscated and you need to search for it. Jesus Microsoft you've been a pain in my ass today. Absolute pain. Why isn't any of this documented? DX -10

In order to obtain AZURE_CLIENT_ID and AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET basically you will need to follow these steps:
Create an Azure Active Directory Application in Microsoft Entra ID:

In Azure portal navigate to MS EntraID.
Click on App registrations and then New registration.
Once the application is created, note down the Application (client) ID. This is your AZURE_CLIENT_ID.

Generate a Client Secret:

In the application settings, go to Certificates & secrets.
Under the Client secrets section, click new client secret.

Generated client secret is your AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET
The error message you're receiving, AuthorizationFailed, indicates that the App Registration you're using doesn't have the necessary permissions to perform the action you're trying to execute. In this case, it's trying to start a virtual machine, but lacks authorization. To resolve this issue, you'll need to ensure that the App Registration has the appropriate permissions. By assigning the Contributor role you're granting the App Registration the ability to start/stop your VM.

Ok, so this is what I have done. However, as stated I am seeing this error:
EnvironmentCredential: invalid tenantID. You can locate your tenantID by following the instructions listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/partner-center/find-ids-and-domain-names
I have double cross checked my TenantId, and have referenced it correctly and it is in the environment ...

Alternatively, you can also find the Tenant ID programmatically using the Azure CLI or PowerShell:  az account show

So I have just ran az login and I see that the tenantId that is returned from that command is exactly the same as the one in my environment ... the tenant id is referenced correctly, yet I still can not do this. This process has to be broken. I am tearing my hair out.

Check that the App Registration has the appropriate permissions to start/stop your VM

I have assigned the correct role as outlined, and I am still seeing the TenantId incorrect error ...
